# C# How to match binding text with Regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string `"{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,FallbackValue='Johan'}"` and I would like to find the `"Name"`, `"TwoWay"`, `"'Johan'"` with Regex.

Now my code is below:

```
Regex r = new Regex("\\s*\\{\\s*Binding\\s+(\\S+)?\\s*,\\s*Mode\\s*=\\s*(\\S+)?(\\s*,\\s*FallbackValue\\s*=\\s*(\\S+)?)?\\s*\\}\\s*");
string testvalue = "{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,FallbackValue='Johan'}";
Match m = r.Match(testvalue);
```

But the match result is:

```
m.Groups[1].Value===>"Name"
m.Groups[2].Value===>"TwoWay,FallbackValue='Johan'"
m.Groups[3].Value===>""
```

So where is wrong? Can you recommend me a better regular expression?

Comment: ^\s*?\{\s*?Binding\s*?(.*?)\s*\,Mode\s*?=(.*?),FallbackValue\s*?\=\'(.*)\'\s*?}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made the last group optional, remove the `?` at the end:

```
Regex r = new Regex("\\s*\\{\\s*Binding\\s+(\\S+)?\\s*,\\s*Mode\\s*=\\s*(\\S+)?(\\s*,\\s*FallbackValue\\s*=\\s*(\\S+)?)\\s*\\}\\s*");
#                                                                                                                  ___^
```

If you want to make the last group optional, make all the word match not greedy and add the optional mark `?`

```
{\\s*Binding\\s+(\\S*)\\s*,\\s*Mode\\s*=\\s*(\\S+?)(?:\\s*,\\s*FallbackValue\\s*=\\s*(\\S*))?\\s*\\}
#                                             ___^                                   and ___^
```

---

If groups 2 (Mode) or 3 (FallbackValue) can be optional, use:

```
{\s*Binding\s+(\S+?)(?:\s*,\s*Mode\s*=\s*(\S+?))?(?:\s*,\s*FallbackValue\s*=\s*(\S+)?)?\s*\}
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/R5wiOh/6)

Comment: hi, do you know which regular expression can match both string "{Binding %UIC,Mode=TwoWay}" and "{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,FallbackValue='Johan'}" ?

Comment: Hi, can you help me again? i would like to match the string "{Binding Name,FallbackValue='Johan'}" too, i tried it long time at https://regex101.com/r/R5wiOh/5, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex I'd use:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@
    "{\s*Binding\s+(?<name>.+)\s*,\s*Mode\s*=(?<mode>.+)\s*,\s*FallbackValue\s*=\s*'(?<fallback>.+)'\s*}"
);
```